# How can i see code coverage by new commits?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, sonarqube, jacoco

Is there a way to see code coverage by commits not all test coverage?
I want to test my commits before merging and see which lines are not covered. Any plugin for intellij or git command?

I can run all test suit with coverage but it does show all lines coverage.

Comment: You can create a pre-commit hook (with Husky) that runs tests with coverage. I believe if you run tests with --WatchAll you only run the tests that have changed since your last commit. But that may depend on which test framework you are using (I use Jest).